# Openstack cluster for parallel execution?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, cluster, openstack, web-applications

I want to try Ubuntu OpenStack with [Metal-as-a-Service (MaaS)](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/maas) for web application purposes.  I would be using Apache2, PHP, MySQL and Postgres.

If I got 5 or more machines setup and installed all those application would it be able work as cluster, for parallel execution?

For example, would a MySQL insert of 1500 rows be able to execute using resources (RAM, CPU, disk, etc) from multiple machines in the cluster?  For another example, if I got 1000 requests to the site, would Apache and PHP be able to use multiple machines to handle the requests?

Basically, could I use OpenStack to create a cluster that would perform a lot faster than a single server without OpenStack would?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use OpenStack to create a Ubuntu-based web stack/cluster that can take advantage parallel processing, and therefore (at least in theory) perform better than a an implementation on a single server.

For that matter, it's also possible to do this without OpenStack.  All the applications you mention support clustering and/or load balancing, so it's possible to install them on two or more computers to split the resource load among multiple computers or cluster members.  And, yes, a cluster would (or at least *should*) perform better than a single server, although, as is always the case, how it's configured matters a lot, so you need to make sure you get it configured properly.